# Markdown Node.js package that renders in user's typing area directly?

Tags: node.js, package

I would like to know if there is a Node.js package that can render Markdown in the user typing area directly like [UseCanvas.com](https://usecanvas.com/)
does. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I think that you should be looking at frontend solutions for this. From the node.js side it should just be plain-text. E.g, https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do this on the front-end if you want this sort of functionality. You can still achieve it with the following [marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked) npm package